# Complément de temps qualifiant une action infréquente, mais pas un état infréquent

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

Des expressions comme « de temps en temps » ou « de temps à autre » peuvent qualifier soit des états qui sont réalisés pendant des intervalles de temps avec des espaces longs durant lesquel l'état n'est pas réalisé, soit des actions qui ont lieu infréquemment.

```
-----+++---------++----------++++------------+++--------  état infréquent

------|-------|----------------|----|--------------|----  action infréquente
```

Pour désigner spécifiquement un état infréquent, on peut utiliser l'expression « par moments ».

> J'entends de la musique par moments.

Y a-t-il une expression qui s'appliquerait spécifiquement à une action infréquente ?

> J'entends des coups secs `______`.

« J'entends des coups secs par moments » signifierait des séries de coups secs, mettons, espacés de quelques secondes, le tout arrivant tous les quelques jours. Et si je veux dire qu'il y a un coup sec de temps en temps, avec un grand espace entre les coups, y a-t-il une expression plus précise ?

(La question m'est venue en expliquant « par moments » à un non-natif.)

Comment: Je tenterais « par intermittence » ou, plus simplement, « parfois ».

Comment: @Édouard Ce sont d'autres possibilités, mais elles s'appliqueraient aussi à un état intermittent.

Comment: Le TLFi propose pour « par intermittence » le sens « à intervalles irréguliers »; il me semble que le point A de « parfois » dans le TLFi convient également.

Comment: Les synonymes proposés par le TLFi pour "intermittent" donnent d'autres pistes: "sporadique", "occasionnel", etc.

Comment: Réciproquement, pour un état infréquent ou variable, voir [How to say “on and off” as in doing something intermittently for a period of time](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11497/how-to-say-on-and-off-as-in-doing-something-intermittently-for-a-period-of-tim)

Comment: Malgré sa compréhensibilité et son étymologie, infréquent est tellement rare en français qu'il pourrait être qualifié d'anglicisme.

Comment: @jlliagre `in-` est un préfixe très productif. Je ne vois pas ce qu'il a d'anglicisme.

Comment: D'après Google Ngram ( https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frequent%2Cinfrequent&year_start=1950&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=10 ) , "infrequent" apparaît environ 10 fois moins que "frequent" en anglais alors qu'en français ( https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=frequent%2Cinfrequent&year_start=1950&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=10 ) "infréquent" apparaît environ 10 000 fois moins que "fréquent", d'où mon commentaire. Je n'avais probablement jamais rencontré "infréquent" avant cette question, le TLFI ne le connais pas non plus.

Answer (score 5):

« Par moments » ou « de temps à autres » ou quelle que soit ta tournure favorite va bien, c'est l'autre partie de la phrase qu'il faut modifier :

> J'entends **un coup sec**, par moments. Je vais demander à mon garagiste de jeter un coup d'œil dans le moteur.

Comment: Oui, il faut passer de "des" à "un".

Answer (score 3):

Au delà des compléments de temps tu peux utiliser la notion **d'aléatoire**, une action infréquente revenant de manière aléatoire dans le temps :

> J'entends des coups secs **aléatoirement**.

Answer (score 3):

> J'entends des coups secs **sporadiquement**.
>
> J'entends des coups secs **occasionnels**.

(J'y ai pensé en lisant [How to say "on and off" as in doing something intermittently for a period of time](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11497/how-to-say-on-and-off-as-in-doing-something-intermittently-for-a-period-of-tim))

Comment: En dehors d'un contexte strictement scientifique il me semble qu'on emploierait plus facilement la périphrase de l'adverbe *de façon sporadique*.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le sens "très rare", il y a plus d'adjectifs que d'adverbes:

accidentel, exceptionnel, extraordinaire, inaccoutumé, inhabituel, insolite, inusité, inusuel, singulier