# How to say "on and off" as in doing something intermittently for a period of time

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

If I wanted to say "to do something on and off" I'm unsure how to express the "on and off" part.

A literal translation might be "de faire quelque chose sur et en dehors" but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Related: for an occasional activity rather than something that comes and goes, see [Complément de temps qualifiant une action infréquente, mais pas un état infréquent](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/compl%C3%A9ment-de-temps-qualifiant-une-action-infr%C3%A9quente-mais-pas-un-%C3%A9tat-infr%C3%A9que)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the time pattern: French and English don't break them up in exactly the same way.

For a habitual action like “I play tennis on and off”, you could say “*Je joue au tennis **à certaines périodes***”; this has no implication on which of the on and off periods are the longer ones. Some other possibilities tend imply shorter on periods: “*de manière sporadique*”, “*sporadiquement*”, “*de façon intermittente*”, “*par intermittence*”. As for “*de temps à autre*” or “*de temps en temps*” or “*à l'occasion*”, they can mean “now and then” or “once in a while” (i.e. there are no lasting on periods, just the occasional game) as well as “on and off”.

For an interrupted activity like “I knit on and off, when I'm not helping a customer”, you can say “*Je tricote **par moments**, quand je ne suis pas occupé avec un client*”.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive list. The sense I'm trying to get is "I have studied X on and off for the last 10 years" meaning a year or two of study, a break of a year or two, repeat...

Comment: @mrbaboo “Par intermittence” sounds ok for this. But if it's for a CV you may want to be more specific with dates anyway.

Comment: @Gilles, What is CV?

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper CV = [curriculum vitae](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curriculum_vitae#English) = [résumé](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9#English)

Answer (score 4):

> De temps en temps
>
> De temps à autre

These two have the same meaning, it means 'from time to time'.
The latter is slightly more formal and could indicate a slightly lesser frequency.

> De façon intermittente

It means directly 'intermittently'; it's more precise than the two above.

Answer (score -3):

If you want say something like switch on or switch off you must say :

> Mettre quelque-chose en marche ou à l'arrêt.

You can't say :

> Mettre quelque-chose en marche **ET** à l'arrêt.

because it's one or the other but not the two together.

Comment: Tout simplement "allumer" et "éteindre"

Comment: « To do something on and off » signifie faire quelque chose à certains moments mais pas à d'autres. Ça peut désigner une activité qu'on alterne avec d'autres, ou qu'on pratique à certaines périodes mais pas à d'autres. Traduire par allumer/éteindre est un contresens.